# What is required on web server to send email using PHP/HTML form using Nginx?

Tags: php, email, nginx, webforms, webserver

I currently have a static website that I am trying to send an email form from. I am using a simple HTML form with fields such as name, email, message, etc. The PHP form is also very straight forward. I don't think there are any problems with the code. In fact, the code is basically exactly like any online tutorial you'd find (http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php). I think the problem has to do with the config on the server. I have a Digital Ocean server with Nginx. At first, when I tried to submit the email form I was getting a 405 error. Now that I handle 405 errors in the config file, I am getting the PHP form as a download when I hit the submit button. What do I need to install on the server or include in the config file to make this PHP email form work?

**Edit/Update:** I have installed Postfix on my web server and am able to successfully send emails from command line using Postfix to different emails outside the server (for instance, I can send from my root user to my personal email addresses on Gmail, etc.). I now have another problem...

- This still doesn't help me on the front-end. When I try to click the submit button on the web page form it is still just downloading the PHP file. I think I am missing something in the php.ini folder and maybe some other things as well. Even though I have mail set up on the server, the PHP action button has no idea that it's set up or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a Mail Transport Agent (MTA) like postfix or exim4. I think you can configure nginx to rely emails to another smtp server.

Another way, would be installing [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and connect it with an email sending service as sendgrid, mandrill, sparkpost, etc.

**Edit:**
I personally recomend a sending service as they have white-listed IP for their sending services plus you save memory in your VPS server (as an MTA daemon is not required to run there).
I'm using sparkpost for a few projects and is working perfectly. They have a pretty high limit for a free account.

With any service you choose, ensure to enable DKIM and SPF to avoid been detected as spam.

Comment: Which of these do you recommend and why?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying which you recommend. I have followed some of your steps but am stuck at something else now. I edited my main post, do you mind taking another look now?

Comment: I belive that you have to modify your php.ini and add the option:   sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

Comment: I have done that as well... still nothing, unfortunately.